# Can we express sum of two sinusoids with different frequencies as a sum of two other sinusoids?

Tags: trigonometry

Can we express the sum of two sinusoids with different frequencies and with different amplitudes as a sum of two other sinusoids with same frequencies as that of the original two sinusoids? for example,

$a\cdot \sin(b\cdot x+c)+d\cdot \sin(e\cdot x+f)=p\cdot \sin(b\cdot x+t) +q\cdot \sin(e\cdot x+r)$ and are there infinite possibilities like this? And if so can we fix one one of the two sinusoids like, $a\cdot \sin(b\cdot x+c)+d\cdot \sin (e\cdot x+f)=p\cdot \sin(b\cdot x+t) +4.5\sin(e\cdot x+\frac{\pi}{4})$ or $p\cdot \sin (b\cdot x+t)+p\cdot \sin (e\cdot x+\frac{\pi}{4}).$

I have tried but failed. Can anyone help? I am new to here. Please correct me if I am wrong
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! Please use MathJax to format the math in your question, it will help you receive a high quality answer. Three is a basic tutorial here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't.
Let's rewrite your identity like this:
$$a\sin(bx+c)-p\sin(bx+t) = d\sin(ex+f)-q\sin(ex+r).$$
If you derive $4n$ times (say) you get:
$$\big(\frac{b}{e}\big)^{4n}(a\sin(bx+c)-p\sin(bx+t)) = d\sin(ex+f)-q\sin(ex+r).$$
Now fix $x$ so that both RHS and LHS are not null (it exists since frequencies are different, you can check it) and take the limit for $n\rightarrow +\infty$. Again, frequencies are different. Assuming $b<e$ you then get a contradiction.